# How get HTML tag value from UIWebView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I want to display the URL in my label form that following code by using HTML Tags, so please help me solve it

```
<p> <span id="link" style="word-break:break-all;" ng-bind="link"></span> </p>

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) 
{ 

 let htmlString = liveWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.someGlobalVariable")! 
htmlString = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('Start').disabled = false;")! 
print("******",htmlString) 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks every one finally i find the solution:

Comment: htmlString = liveWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('link').innerHTML")!

Answer (score 1):

```
let htmlString:String = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('link').innerHTML")!
```

Answer (score 0):

use **`NSDataDetector`** class can match dates, addresses, links, phone numbers and transit information. *[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector)*.

```
let htmlString = "<p><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk\">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk</a></p>\n"
let types: NSTextCheckingType = .Link
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

guard let detect = detector else {
    return
}

let matches = detect.matchesInString(htmlString, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, htmlString.characters.count))

for match in matches {
    print(match.URL!)
}
```